# How get the parent role of a list of roles in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I try to find a way that allows me to recover the strongest role from the list I defined in the security file Symfony `security.yml`

Suppose I have the following hierarchy :

```
ROLE_A: [ROLE_B,ROLE_C]
ROLE_B: [ROLE_D]
```

In a method that I have to develop, I am supposed to pass a role list (A, B and C) in this case and recover the strongest role (A).

Can you come up with ideas?

Comment: For this hierarchy: `ROLE_A: [ROLE_B]; ROLE_C: [ROLE_D]` `getStrongest(ROLE_A. ROLE_C)` what should return?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. Out of luck, I had to have the role hierarchical logic in `User Entity` like in an associative array.

Then create a method as `getParentRole()` to return desired parent `ROLE`.

OR

If you are using `FOSUserBundle` and your Application needs a group level classification of `User` entity, Consider using [Group feature](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/groups.html) available in `FOSUserBundle`

Hope this helps!